# Why does my StreamReader.ReadLine () in F# not read \n as a new line?

Tags: f#, streamreader, msdn

I am currently trying to read a file as this:

```
53**7****\n6**195***\n*98****6*\n8***6***3\n4**8*3**1\n7***2***6\n*6****28*\n***419**5\n****8**79\n
```

And write it into the screen, but with new lines instead of the /n.

On the msdn description of the method StreamReader.ReadLine () it says that:
A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed. The returned value is null if the end of the input stream is reached.

Why does my program not interpret `\n` as a new line?

Comment: You're saying you have a file with a single line that includes those \n's? If so, then those are not line feed characters, those are two-character strings that look like how we represent line feed.

Comment: You'd need to replace the "\\n" substrings with the actual `Environment.NewLine` string.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem is that the documentation for `ReadLine` is talking about the `'\n'` (single) character, while you actually have a `"\\n"` two-character string.

In C#, `\` is used as an escape character - for example, `\n` represents the character with ASCII value of 10. However, files are *not* parsed according to C# rules (that's a good thing!). Since your file doesn't have the literal 10-characters, they aren't interpreted as endlines, and rightly so - the literal translation in ASCII would be (92, 110).

Just use `Split` (or `Replace`), and you'll be fine. Basically, you want to replace `"\\n"` with `"\n"` (or better, `Environment.NewLine`).

Answer (score 1):

I used @Mark Seemann's method by letting `let s = inputStream.ReadToEnd ()` and thereby importing the string you are typing in directly. I am able to print out the same output as you with your do-while loop, but i have to use this recursive printFile method:

`let rec printFile (reader : System.IO.StreamReader) = 
  if not(reader.EndOfStream) then
     let line = reader.ReadLine ()
     printfn "%s" line
     printFile reader`

This however does not recognize the \n as new lines - do you know why as i see the methods as very similar? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I can't reproduce the issue. This seems to work fine:

```
let s = "53**7****\n6**195***\n*98****6*\n8***6***3\n4**8*3**1\n7***2***6\n*6****28*\n***419**5\n****8**79\n"

open System.IO

let strm = new MemoryStream()
let sw = new StreamWriter(strm)
sw.Write s
sw.Flush ()
strm.Position <- 0L

let sr = new StreamReader(strm)
while (not sr.EndOfStream) do
    let line = sr.ReadLine ()
    printfn "%s" line
```

This prints

```
53**7****
6**195***
*98****6*
8***6***3
4**8*3**1
7***2***6
*6****28*
***419**5
****8**79
```

Comment: That's not the same thing ; the question wording implies (like scrwtp added in comment) that the given text **IS** the current file and not it's textual representation. To reproduce the same condition using your current code you need to escape `\n` (as pointed by Luaan) or use a verbatim string.